# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. this было 0xFDFDFDFD

Tags: c++

Имеется код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>   
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout("output.txt");
    std::ifstream fin("input.txt");
    int N, K, P;
    fin >> N >> K >> P;
    int max = 0;
    int current = 0;
    bool error = false;
    char command;
    int num, fuel, temp;
    std::stack<int> **barge = new std::stack<int>*[K];
    for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i)
    {
        barge[i] = new std::stack<int>;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N && !error; ++i)
    {
        fin >> command >> num >> fuel;
        if (command == '+')
        {
            barge[num]->push(fuel);
            current++;
            if (barge[num]->size() > P)
            {
                error = true;
                break;
            }
            if (current > max)
                max = current;
        }
        else if (command == '-')
        {
            if (barge[num]->size() == 0)
            {
                error = true;
                break;
            }
            temp = barge[num]->top();
            barge[num]->pop();
            current--;
            if (temp != fuel)
            {
                error = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i)
    {
        delete barge[i];
    }
    delete[] barge;
    if (error || current > 0)
        fout << "Error";
    else
        fout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

В visual studio 2017 выдает "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. this было 0xFDFDFDFD". Не пойму что не так.

Comment: Компилируется! Отличайте компиляцию от выполнения программы!

Comment: @Harry Ой, да, сглупил. Но все равно, что в программе не так? Я где-то -> неправильно использую может

Comment: Проверяйте выход за границы массива.

Comment: Откуда ж я знаю? Мне ж, чтоб понять, что именно не так, нужно не только ее скомпилировать, но и ваши данные в нее засунуть. А их у меня нет...

Comment: @Harry думал тут что-то очевидно не так, но раз уж без входных данных никак то ладно. Вот они:

6 1 2
+ 1 1
+ 1 2
- 1 2
- 1 1
+ 1 3
- 1 3

Comment: Ладно, я уже понял что было не так. Проблема в создании динамического массива

Comment: О! Вот он - *наилучший* результат, который только можно получить - это разобраться **самостоятельно**! Поздравляю (без малейшего сарказма)!